# dplyr sample_n returns different number of rows in table

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics

I am working with dplyr and sample_n in R and trying to get an even group of rows to work with in my data frame.

So, I have a data set, head of data as follows:

```
> head(SEH)
    Time.Level Demo.Age SEH.Total
92         PRE       12       110
335        PRE       12        80
720        MID       14        85
196        MID       11        95
408        POST      18        60
184        POST      10        99
```

I separated out the data into three different data frames according to time level. So I have a SEH.pre, an SEH.mid and an SEH.post. I then do a describe and I know I have uneven groups of pre, mid, post. So, I want to random sample out pre, mid, post groups to be an even size. For example, I have the SEH.pre and SEH.mid group n sizes below:

```
> describe(SEH.pre)
            vars   n    
Time.Level*    1 887  
Demo.Age       2 883 
SEH.Total      3 887 

> describe(SEH.mid)
            vars   n  
Time.Level*    1 894  
Demo.Age       2 872 
SEH.Total      3 894
```

So, now I run sample_n on the SEH.pre thinking that I can re-sample to an n of 860 across all columns. I run the following command:

```
SEH.pre2 <- sample_n(SEH.pre, 860, replace = FALSE)
```

And then I describe and the Demo.Age is less than the rest:

```
> describe(SEH.pre2)
            vars   n ...
Time.Level*    1 860  
Demo.Age       2 856 
SEH.Total      3 860
```

I feel like a big idiot but I cannot figure out why this is. I have tried it multiple times and Demo.Age varies from 856 to 859, but is never 860. I want all three columns to be 860. How do I do this? And why am I mis-thinking that sample_n should create even groups out of uneven?

Comment: Is this using `describe` from `psych`? `n` should be the number of non-missing values I think, there are missing values in `Demo.Age` and you sample different numbers of them each time.

Comment: @Marius is correct, the `describe` function from `psych` counts the non-missing values for the column `n`. Try running `sum(is.na(SEH.pre2$Demo.Age))` and see if it's 4

Comment: This makes complete sense. Duh. Thanks!